# Is it possible to use dataLoader with multiple keys in GraphQL?

Tags: c#, dataloader, hotchocolate

For [GroupDataLoader](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/dataloader/#group-dataloader) by Hot Chocolate, you can only pass 1 key in `.LoadAsync()`. I think it is same for [BatchDataLoader](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/dataloader/#batch-dataloader) as well but I am intrested in group data loader.

If we go by use cases then `Group Data Loader` works if I am doing look up using one key.

ex: here, I can fetch all records per location.

```
public Task<List<Location>> GetLocationsAsync(
    string location,
    LocationGroupDataLoader location,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    => location.LoadAsync(location, cancellationToken); <-- Want to use it like this (location, type, ....)
```

Now let's say this query brings up 20,000 records with the same location. Here, There are 10,000 records with `Type=City`.

1. How can I apply `Type` filter along with `Location`?
2. Is it even possible with `DataLoader`?
3. If no, then what will be most efficient way? Scrap `DataLoader` and write regular query with `filters` which can be leveraged when querying DB?